# Wrong choice of words in info message -- "close" instead of "reopen"

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, re-open

When moving the mouse above the [reopen] button below a *closed* question which I have voted to reopen, I see the text "You voted to reopen. 3 more votes from other users are needed to *close* this question."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed in next build, watch for rev `DATE.1177`.